# What, if any, are reasonable further tests for evaluation of cryptogenic stroke?

Tags: neurology

What is considered a "complete" workup of cryptogenic stroke?

If someone presents with symptoms consistent with stroke and receives:
PE
EKG and external monitoring,
MRI with contrast/MRA of head and neck, (MRI revealed small area (4mm) of ischemia in parietal lobe, without edema, not present on previous MRI 4 years earlier for first migraine),
CTA of head and neck (neg),
Tranthoracic Echocardiogram (neg),
Transesophageal Echocardiogram (neg),
carotid duplex and transcranial ultrasonography (neg),
CBC w/ diff, metabolic profile, coag studies, everything including serum porcelain levels (all neg)
hypercoagulability studies (results pending),
Hematological w/u for occult cancer (neg),
d/c with a subcutaneous loop recorder to r/o paroxysmal atrial fib

Is this a complete workup?

Would further w/u be of any benefit (against the possible risk) in finding the origin of the stroke?

Edited to add: As this may be an important detail, the patient is young. (30)